# Redirect any other routes to "/" in Router (React JS)

Tags: reactjs, regex, react-router-dom

I have a Router component which routes to different elements depending on the path:

```
<Router>
    <Route exact path='/' component={RouterPage}/>
    <Route exact path='/sign-up' component={SignUp}/>
    <Route exact path='/lobby' component={Lobby}/>
    <Route exact path='/game' component={Game}/>
    <Route exact path='/game/host' component={Host}/>
    <Route exact path='/debug' component={Debug}/>
</Router>
```

However, I want to redirect any other path to `"/"`.
For example, if  the path were to be `"/qwerty"`, it would get routed to `"/"`.

I tried using `<Redirect from="*" to="/" />`, but it overrides the other defined routes as well.

How could this issue be solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a regex-based route, like:

```
<Route path='/!(sign-up|lobby|game|game/host|debug)' component={RouterPage} />
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked perfectly, I did not know that it was regex based.

Comment: @OsamaSalman you are welcome, I'm glad the issue is sorted out.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `Link` inside your component and add somewhere like header in that page.

```
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
<Link to="/"> Home</Link>
```